# Learning about Markov Chains

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains

I am trying to learn about how to use markov chains for complicated probability problems. I have been looking for different materials to learn these but haven't had much luck. Does anyone have any papers or materials that they would suggest?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/

Comment: Here's some resources: http://hbpms.blogspot.com/2008/05/stage-3-probability-and-stochastic.html